# Unable to get x,y position in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add some text inside rectangles in d3.

```
var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "g")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d[columns[0]]) + ",0)";
            });
var count = 0;
    state.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) {
                return d.val;
            })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return y(d.y1);               <<<===== Line 1
            })
            .attr("height", function(d) {

                return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
            })
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return x(d.x);                   <<<===== Line 2
            })
            .style("fill", function(d,i) {
            return colorSet(i);
            })
            .attr("id", function(d, i) {
                return col[i];
            })
            .attr("onclick", fun)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform",function(d) {
                   var xvalue =x(d.x);         <<<===== Line 3
                    var yValue = y(d.y1);      <<<===== Line 4
                    return "translate(" + xvalue + ", " + yValue + ")";
                })
            .text("AAA");
```

First when i am adding the rectangles I am able to get x and y positons x(d.x) and y(d.y1) as mentioned by 'line 1' and 'line 2' but when I am again trying to get x and y value in 'line 3' and 'line 4' I am getting wrong values. 
Can anyone point out what is wrong with this code???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think in the code, we are appending 'text' element to 'rect' so here the append function will return 'text' element, on this text element now we are setting transform attribute with callback by passing text element's data (argument d), but actually text element doesn't have any data, If you want to see that write one console.log(d) before line number 3, and var xvalue = x(d.x); Here we can access x function but d is undefined, on this undefined d we can't access x value as d.x, hope you understood.

Comment: @saikiran.vsk can you suggest as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot append a text element inside a rect element. You need to make a g element and append both in that.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cool Blue mentioned you cannot append text element inside a `rect` element so try this code:

```
var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + x(d[columns[0]]) + ",0)";
        });
     var count = 0;
     state.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) {
            return d.val;
        })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.y1);              
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {

            return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
        })
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.x);                   
        })
        .style("fill", function(d,i) {
        return colorSet(i);
        })
        .attr("id", function(d, i) {
            return col[i];
        })
        .attr("onclick", fun);

 state.selectAll("text")
        .data(function(d) {
            return d.val;
        })
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("transform",function(d) {
               var xvalue =x(d.x);         
                var yValue = y(d.y1);      
                return "translate(" + xvalue + ", " + yValue + ")";
            })
        .text("AAA");
```